# Part of state of app remains after onDestroy is called

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, ondestroy

Not really sure how to describe this problem since I can't really grasp what is going on.

I have an app with a single activity in which fragments are attached and detached.

When the app goes into paused state and back to active all works fine.

But when onDestroy is called and the app is restarted there seem to be some information of the previous states of the fragments or activity left.

Controls that worked before don't connect between the fragments and the main activity and the fragments.

When I swipe the app away from the list of the previously executed it can restart and all works as expected again.

This is how I log what is going on when the problem occurs:

```
Main activity: onPaus, 
Main activity: onStop 
Fragments: destroyView,
Fragments: onDestroy
Fragments: onDetach 
Main activity: onDestroy
```

At one time I thought this was related to an OsmDroid view as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28795065/controls-not-affecting-map-efter-device-orientation-change) but I'm not sure this must be the case.

Comment: How do you know onDestroy is called? Please be specific. Did you put a logging statement in onDestroy to confirm that it is indeed called when you think it is.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Yes. What I log is that onPaus, onStop and onDestroy is called for the activity. And also destroyView, onDestroy and onDetach is called from the fragments between onStop and onDestroy.

Comment: When the activity goes to the background, its state is saved through the onsaveInstance() method which include the state of the views. When it is created again, you can check what was saved through the onCreate() method's bundle

Comment: @Quanturium You mean onSaveInstanceState(Bundel b) ?

Comment: Yes this is what is called when you app goes to the background. That same bundle is passed as a parameter of your onCreate() method when the activity is recreated from a previous saved state.

Comment: @Quanturium I'm not sure why this happens, but I played around with that function and when I forgot to call super.onSaveInstanceState(b); it started to work as I want. I assume it previously saved some state of a View in a bad way. Is there a way I can see what is saved by a Bundle? toString gave quite pointless data just: Bundle[{}].

Comment: By removing the super.onSaveInstanceState() you are basically removing the saving state of your views and probably an other bunch of stuff. This is not recommended. What I would advice you to do is taking a look at the Android life cycle http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html and try understand it carefully. Find out what the issues exactly are regarding your views / previous state and fix them one by one. Keep in mind the best practices and default behavior is to restore the activity exactly how it was before it was destroyed. Not starting from scratch.